# C-style functions in Objective-C iOS application

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

As many of us know - we can use C-style functions in our Objective-C iOS applications like this one, for instance:

```
NSString* returnTen() {
    return @"Ten";
}
```

But when is it reasonable to use C style function instead of regular Objective-C method? Or just when in general one would use C-style functions in iOS application?

Comment: How do you define C-style functions? Because C neither defines `NSString` nor supports `@""` strings.

Comment: In implementation file, above @implementation directive

Comment: Or within the @implementation. Works just as well.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't matter. But what is the advantage of using them anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But when is it reasonable to use C style function instead of regular Objective-C method?

It's entirely *reasonable* to use a function instead of a class and methods whenever you want to define an operation that isn't tied to an object and its data. Doing that is sort of antithetical to the object oriented programming style, so most people would normally prefer to do things with classes when possible, but it's certainly not *unreasonable* to write a function here and there if it suits your purpose.

> Or just when in general one would use C-style functions in iOS application?

The obvious case is when you're using a library or framework that provides functions. There are a great many of these. Some examples:

- C-based system frameworks such as Core Foundation and Core Graphics
- POSIX/C standard library
- any 3rd party C library you happen to need

Also, consider that blocks are *very* similar to functions, differing mainly in that they have state associated with them. Blocks are used extensively in modern Objective-C, and in many cases they simplify API's by replacing or avoiding delegate methods and such.

Comment: As a matter of fact, the Objective-C API expects you to use C functions in some cases.  For instance, there is the `sortedArrayUsingFunction` method of NSArray that takes a function reference as a parameter.

Comment: I'd call that the Foundation API, but yes, absolutely. And I'm obviously splitting hairs here -- Obj-C wouldn't be much fun without Foundation.

Comment: I never know what to call it -- I'm not much good at remembering the fancy terminology.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Caleb and your comments Hot Licks!

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong about using what you call "C-Style functions" in an iOS project. Objective-C is a superset of C - so in a way, you're writing C all the time anyway.

Usually, you'd be eligible to use plain C functions when the purpose of the function is very atomic and/or when you'd like to "inline" the thing the functions does in the rest of your code. For example, you could be in need of a function that evaluates the biggest of two given integers. Because this is such a "small" thing to do and not worth the (admittedly tiny) overhead of sending a full blown Objective-C message (that behind the curtains needs to make use of `objc_msgSend()` in order to work), you could implement it as a small C function. So, instead of

```
- (int)biggerIntegerOf:(int)a and:(int)b {
    return a > b ? a : b;
}
```

you could use

```
static inline int max(int a, int b) {
    return a > b ? a : b;
}
```

By specifying "inline" you give the compiler a hint that says "At the place(s) in my code where I call the function max(), you can instead just inline its contents right in place as if I copy and pasted it there".

Comment: Nice answer, thank you Elwisz. But what if I would want to return from that little function NSString?

Comment: There's nothing that can stop you from doing so. Remember, you're not really returning a NSString but rather a pointer to a NSString from the function. So there's really nothing special about it doing it with plain C.